# Troubleshooting In-App Purchases in TestFlight

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

In react-native app , I am encountering an issue with in-app purchases in my iOS app. When I install the app directly from Xcode, in-app purchases work seamlessly. However, after archiving the app and installing it from TestFlight, I am repeatedly prompted with the sandbox sign-in popup. After entering the correct sandbox tester account credentials, nothing happens, and the popup persists.

Used a sandbox tester account for testing.
Reset the sandbox environment, signed out, uninstalled, and reinstalled from TestFlight.
Checked in-app purchase status in App Store Connect (in the "Ready to Submit" state).

Comment: AM also getting same issue from a long time